# IFTTT: How do I programatically trigger on/off a IFTTT applet?

Tags: c#, ifttt

How do I programatically trigger on/off a IFTTT applet?

I want to trigger on/off using C# Program

https://ifttt.com/applets/DKPUF3MH-turn-on-off-sonoff

Comment: Sounds like this question would be better suited for an IFTTT product forum. Is there a programming problem we can help with?

Comment: Please review updated question